# TypeScript: How to use a variable inferred type to define another variable with the same type, outside of a class

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have this variable:

```
const x = {
  name: 'shachar',
} as const;
```

This variable has the inferred type of

```
{
  name: 'shachar';
}
```

I want to use that type to create another type alias like this:

```
const y: {[key in keyof *TYPE_OF_X*]: boolean} = {
  name: true;
}
```

Without having to define this type explicitly.

This can be done if I was inside a class:

```
class MyClass {
  x = {
   name: 'shachar',
  } as const;

  y: {[key in keyof this['x']]: boolean} = {
    name: true;
  }
}
```

But can this be done if I'm outside a class?

I've also found the following workaround:

```
class MyClass {
    x = {
      name: 'shachar',
    } as const;
}

const x = (new MyClass()).x;

const y: { [key in keyof MyClass['x']]: boolean} = {
    name: true,
}
```

But it doesn't look really good, it requires me to add a redundant class, and might make the code look messy when I repeat this method over and over...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pseudocode is already very close, using `key in keyof typeof x` will work as expected:

```
const x = {
  name: 'shachar',
} as const;

const y: {[key in keyof typeof x]: boolean} = {
  name: true,
};
```